# Windows lock screen has foreign language links

Tags: windows, malware, lock-screen

There are two icons that look like globes with some foreign language (Chinese, Japanese, maybe) text that appear on my lock screen, and I'm not sure how they got there. One of them takes me to

> www.msn.com/ja-jp/news/opinion/lockscreen/halloween_01/ar-AAiFLeh?ocid=ems.msn.10212016

and the other link takes me to

> www.msn.com/ja-jp/travel/news/lockscreen/halloween_02/ss-BBvCP8B?ocid=ems.msn.10212016

I'm not sure if this meant to be a Halloween joke or something. Here is an image of my lock screen:

[image]

Could this be malicious?

Comment: You have feature enabled that rotates selected images by Microsoft?  In other words did you select that lock screen image?

Comment: I can tell you have, and no; it's NOT malicious.  If you don't like it disable the feature

Comment: It's called Windows Spotlight

Comment: Windows Spotlight were the keywords I needed for google to respond with helpful suggestions, this [guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/243263/how-to-disable-ads-on-your-windows-10-lock-screen/) shows how to disable the feature.@Ramhound Thanks!