# How did the language on the lock screen change to Chinese?

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen

On my Windows 10 Pro, the lock screen language switched to Chinese and
then back to English on its own, even though I made no changes:

[image]

Why did this happen?

Comment: Images for Windows Spotlight are regional based. Windows uses geolocation in addition to determining what your user profile regional settings are. [In this case it’s also based on what region the image is configured to show in.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-spotlight-suddenly-decided-to-use-thai/1f945b0c-1c87-4a2c-84b9-83f9a4788e9e?page=2) in other words it’s a bug

Comment: This isn’t a new issue[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1140399/windows-lock-screen-has-foreign-language-links)

Comment: BTW, if you use a VPN with exit point in another country, that likely would further confuse the screen issue, if you let MS determine what to show. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/personalize-your-lock-screen-81dab9b0-35cf-887c-84a0-6de8ef72bea0#WindowsVersion=Windows_11